# Convert contents of a config file to Dictionary, if possible

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, amazon-s3

I am pulling config files from S3 bucket. The contents of it is returned as String. My objective is to convert this string of config contents to a dictionary.
Here is how the contents in the config file looks like:

```
[Credentials]
user=user123
pw=pass123

[Tables]
table=1
table=2
```

Comment: Did you try ConfigParser, https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html ?

Comment: I have not. The content of the config file is coming back as string. I do not see how configparser can help here.

Comment: This library may helps: https://github.com/pylover/pymlconf

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConfigParser`.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
config_parser = ConfigParser()
config_parser.read_string(your_config_as_string)
user = config_parser.get('Credentials', 'user')
```

Here, the value of `user` is now `user123` if `your_config_as_string` is as below:

```
[Credentials]
user=user123
pw=pass123
```

If you want to convert the content of the `config_parser` to a dict, you can iterate on `sections` and `options` of `config_parser`.

```
config = {
    section: {
        option: config_parser.get(section, option)
        for option in config_parser.options(section)
    } for section in config_parser.sections()
}
```

This will result in a dict as:
`{'Credentials': {'pw': 'pass123', 'user': 'user123'}}`